# Jetty embedded + Jersey + Weld

Tags: java, jersey, embedded-jetty, weld

I'm trying to implement (into Java SE) a standalone embedded web server, exposing REST application with CDI support.

I followed up a simple tutorial at this link https://techunity.de/blog/integrate-a-rest-service-into-a-standalone-java-application/, but I don't want to use OpenAPI, just simple JAX-RS resource classes.

I set up Gradle as follow, with all required dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.4'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'

    implementation 'jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:3.0.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.0.1'

    implementation 'org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:5.1.0.Final'
    implementation 'org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet-core:5.1.0.Final'

    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:11.0.12'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:11.0.12'

    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi:jersey-cdi1x:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi:jersey-cdi1x-servlet:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi:jersey-weld2-se:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:3.1.0'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.7'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.7'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'it.gym.StartApp'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Then I created the main class:

```
package it.gym;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle;

public class StartApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();

        final Server server = new Server(9000);
        final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");

        context.addEventListener(Listener.using(weld));
        context.setAttribute(
                WeldServletLifecycle.BEAN_MANAGER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
                container.getBeanManager());

        final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(
                ServletContainer.class);
        servletHolder.setInitOrder(1);
        servletHolder.setInitParameter(
                "jersey.config.server.provider.packages",
                "it.gym");

        context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/rest/*");

        server.setHandler(context);

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I created a resource class and a bean class:

```
package it.gym.rest;

import java.util.List;

import it.gym.dao.GymDAO;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

@Path("/")
@RequestScoped
public class GymEndpoint {

    @Inject
    private GymDAO gymDAO;
    
    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public Response test() {
        List<String> entity = gymDAO.getDevices();
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(entity).build();
    }
}
```

```
package it.gym.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped
public class GymDAO {

    public GymDAO() {

    }
    
    public List<String> getDevices() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

When I start the server I get the following error. It seems not to find the GymDAO class as a CDI class, ignoring the @RequestScoped annotation. Can anyone figure out what I'm missing?

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer-15eebbff==org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer@60d52d52{jsp=null,order=1,inst=true,async=true,src=EMBEDDED:null,STARTED}
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:651)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$2(ServletHandler.java:725)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:749)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:392)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:901)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
        at it.gym.StartApp.main(StartApp.java:40)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type GymDAO with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private it.gym.rest.GymEndpoint.gymDAO
  at it.gym.rest.GymEndpoint.gymDAO(GymEndpoint.java:0)

        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:83)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:70)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:51)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier$2.<init>(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:83)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.<init>(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.GenericCdiBeanSupplier.<init>(GenericCdiBeanSupplier.java:37)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.bind(CdiComponentProvider.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider.bind(CdiComponentProvider.java:182)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiServerComponentProvider.bind(CdiServerComponentProvider.java:50)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceModelConfigurator.bindWithComponentProvider(ResourceModelConfigurator.java:193)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceModelConfigurator.bindProvidersAndResources(ResourceModelConfigurator.java:150)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceModelConfigurator.init(ResourceModelConfigurator.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:359)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:310)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:309)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:338)
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:633)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type GymDAO with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private it.gym.rest.GymEndpoint.gymDAO
  at it.gym.rest.GymEndpoint.gymDAO(GymEndpoint.java:0)

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:367)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:285)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateProducer(Validator.java:414)
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.validateProducer(InjectionTargetService.java:36)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.validate(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:153)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:81)
        ... 43 more
14:27:02.984 [Thread-0] INFO org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-002001: Weld SE container 944b54c2-e094-44a2-ba2b-0ae8d247d9aa shut down
Weld SE container 944b54c2-e094-44a2-ba2b-0ae8d247d9aa shut down by shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 1):

Jetty team here.

I went ahead and added an example project for it at

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jersey-weld

See the `jetty-11.0.x` branch for your version.

*Yeah, we use maven. There's 3 committers to maven also as committers to Jetty.*

Here's the highlights.

First, you'll need the correct dependencies, this is all you need.

```
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.4'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'

    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:11.0.12'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-cdi:11.0.12'
    
    implementation 'org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet-core:4.0.3.Final'

    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:3.0.4'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-cdi2-se:3.0.4'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:3.0.4'
```

We rely on transitive dependencies to pull in what other dependencies we need.

Then you'll want to wire up `jetty-cdi` to the weld implementation.

Replace ...

```java
context.addEventListener(Listener.using(weld));
context.setAttribute(
   WeldServletLifecycle.BEAN_MANAGER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
   container.getBeanManager());
```

... with ...

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.cdi.CdiServletContainerInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.cdi.CdiDecoratingListener;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener;

context.setInitParameter(
    CdiServletContainerInitializer.CDI_INTEGRATION_ATTRIBUTE, 
    CdiDecoratingListener.MODE);
context.addServletContainerInitializer(new CdiServletContainerInitializer());
context.addServletContainerInitializer(new EnhancedListener());
```

This is the weld recommended technique to wire things up with Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tryed with Grizzly and it works like a charm.

Here gradle conf file:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.4'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'

    implementation 'jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:3.0.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:3.0.1'

    implementation 'org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:5.1.0.Final'
    implementation 'org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet-core:5.1.0.Final'

    implementation 'org.glassfish.grizzly:grizzly-http-server:4.0.0'

    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi:jersey-weld2-se:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:3.1.0'

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.7'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.7'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'it.gym.StartApp'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And the main class:

```
package it.gym;

import java.net.URI;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld;

public class StartApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        weld.initialize();

        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.packages("it.gym");

        final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("http://localhost:9000/"),
                resourceConfig);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        server.shutdownNow();
        weld.shutdown();
    }
}
```